# Yii - Javascript click functions not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I'm developing an application in Yii. I'm fairly new to the framework, and I'm having a problem getting certain functions to work. I'm not sure if the problem lies in how I'm importing the javascript file, or if it's something else. I can reconstruct my script in jsFiddle and it works fine (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVRmj/). This example is just a small set of True / False questions.

Here's how I'm importing the javascript file (in the header):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Game Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var BASE_URL = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>";
</script>
<?php
    echo file_get_contents(getcwd() . "/tmpl/game_pages.html");
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/game_pages.js',CClientScript::POS_END);
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/js/puzzle.js',CClientScript::POS_END);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<div id="account-body">
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/game_pages.css" />
```

Everything else is exactly like you see it in the jsFiddle example. The javascript is contained in puzzle.js, as you can see listed above.

I have also tried placing the script inline in the header. In both cases, the script is being called, and *parts of it work*. For example, I'll get alerts and can log things to the console with it, but I don't get alerts when clicking the inputs (click True on #4 in the jsFiddle to see what I'm talking about), nor do I get one when the submit button is pressed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you cleaned the yii assets directory? Maybe it's rendering the cached js file? Just a thought

Comment: Yes, I made sure to check that was not happening. Thanks, though.

Comment: Why you add css by hardcode, but scripts you register by `clientScript`? For link css you also use `clientScript`

Comment: Also where you link to jquery?

Comment: @Sergey jQuery is being called before this in the layout header (main.php before $content)